# Darwin: Thread suspend/wakeup

Tags: ios, multithreading, posix, bsd, mach

**Usage Cases:**

> Thread **A**: Please remove me from the active thread pool, Mr. Scheduler.
>
> Thread **B**: Mr. Scheduler, please add Thread **A** to the active
>   thread pool, *if he isn't there already*

This is a fairly specific, and well-contained problem. Of course, I can use pthread's condition variables to do this - but they solve a more complex problem.

Was wondering if there was a more direct route available. For example, **sigwait**

Answer (score 0):

Thread A:

```
thread_t thread_a = mach_thread_self();
thread_suspend(thread_a);
```

Thread B:

```
thread_resume(thread_a);
```